# How do I correct XSD for JAXB generator?

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb, xjc

I prepared `complexType`, an enum with two attributes:

```
<xsd:complexType name="Action">
    <xsd:simpleContent>
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:enumeration value="A"/>
            <xsd:enumeration value="B"/>
            <xsd:enumeration value="C"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleContent>
    <xsd:attribute name="attrA" type="xsd:string" />
    <xsd:attribute name="attrB" type="xsd:string" />
</xsd:complexType>
```

The problem is, `JAXB` prevents me from creating Java classes for that code, I get the following error:

> When  is used, the base type must be a complexType
>   whose content
>       type is simple, or, only if restriction is specified, a complex type with mixed
>       content and emptiable particle, or, only if extension is specified, a simple type.
>       'string' satisfies none of these conditions.

Online validator showed me my code is corrent one. How do I change this to make `xjc` convert my schema definition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your xsd is not well formed. Try below `complexType`

```
<xs:complexType name="Action">
    <xs:simpleContent>
        <xs:extension base="ActionValue">
            <xs:attribute name="attrA" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:attribute name="attrB" type="xs:string" />
        </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:simpleType name="ActionValue">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:enumeration value="A" />
        <xs:enumeration value="B" />
        <xs:enumeration value="C" />
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

Comment: Works fine. I guess there is no simpler solution?

Comment: In your case i think not